# Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list unsing Bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

i am using bloc to add and remove from am list..

my bloc state is like this,

```
@freezed
class InterestActionState with _$InterestActionState {
  factory InterestActionState({
    required bool isSubmitting,
    required List<String> selectedInterest,
    required Option<Either<InterestFailure, Unit>>
        intrestFailureOrSuccessOption,
  }) = Initial;

  factory InterestActionState.initial() => InterestActionState(
        isSubmitting: false,
        selectedInterest: <String>[],
        intrestFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
      );

  const InterestActionState._();
}
```

also i am adding to the list like this

```
  void addInterestToMyList(
    AddMyList event,
    Emitter<InterestActionState> emit,
  ) {
    emit(state.copyWith(
        selectedInterest: state.selectedInterest..add(event.selectedInterest)));
```

}

and to Remove from the List is

```
 void removeInterestToMyList(
    RemoveFromList event,
    Emitter<InterestActionState> emit,
  ) {
    emit(state.copyWith(
        selectedInterest: state.selectedInterest
          ..remove(event.selectedInterest)));
  }
```

but i keep getting `flutter: Unsupported operation: Cannot add to an unmodifiable list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state.selectedInterest` must be unmodifiable, and `remove` and `add` modify the list in place (it modifies the list and doesn't create a copy).

You can create a copy yourself using `.toList()`:

Add:

```dart
 void addInterestToMyList(
    AddMyList event,
    Emitter<InterestActionState> emit,
  ) {
    emit(state.copyWith(
        selectedInterest: state.selectedInterest.toList()..add(event.selectedInterest)));
```

Remove:

```dart
void removeInterestToMyList(
    RemoveFromList event,
    Emitter<InterestActionState> emit,
  ) {
    emit(state.copyWith(
        selectedInterest: state.selectedInterest.toList()
          ..remove(event.selectedInterest)));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

change your code into:

```
  void addInterestToMyList(
    AddMyList event,
    Emitter<InterestActionState> emit,
  ) {
    emit(state.copyWith(
        selectedInterest: [...state.selectedInterest, event.selectedInterest]));
```

and to remove it, create a new lazy list without editing the original one:

```
emit(state.copyWith(
    selectedInterest: state.selectedInterest.where((e) => e != event.selectedInterest).toList()));
```

this should solve your issue

Comment: what of if is to remove from the list..

Comment: @GbengaBAyannuga edited my answer with the delete as well